# Points division in a game (addition and subtraction and division only)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

> We three are playing a game and within each trial of a game two people **lose** certain amount of **points** and one of them **gains** the **points** lost by the other two.

Here is a preview of the excel file for first few trials:

[image]

> I got the total of the win and loss for each person and then divide the loss of each and then give to the winning person which I later realised was wrong.

I just want to know how to proceed in excel. The winning points can be found using the autosum but the major issue is when I autosum the loss of each inidividual, from that loss how much should I give to both others.

**As it is clear to me now it shouldn't be divided by half as in each trial loss of points is varying.**

Any help is appreciated. I dont know how to attach an excel file here: Otherwise I could have done that. I just want to know the procedure with some detail.

Comment: I voted to close because this is not about math. You need to decide how you want to award winnings according to points; there's no mathematical reason to do it in any particular way.

Answer (score 1):

Just treat the green winnings as positive numbers, the red losses as negative numbers, and add them all up for each person to find the net result for that person.  Then people who have a net negative put money on the table, and then people who have a net positive grab money from the table.  Since the sum of all green numbers $=$ the sum of all red numbers, this will work out perfectly.